# Making link clickable within a CSS3 hover 'after' pseudo element

Tags: css

I've set up some image hover styling based on [this tutorial](http://www.cssscript.com/transparent-image-hover-overlay-with-pure-css-css3/) which creates the hover styling using the `before` and `after` pseudo-elements.

Works (and looks) great but I need to be able to insert buttons/links within the hover content but due to this being styled on the pseudo-elements, the `after` is preventing the buttons/links to be clickable.

It looks like the below, I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/L35azg6v/) to demonstrate what I am wanting to do - as you'll notice, the link isn't clickable on hover and I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a simple way of making this link clickable without having to completely change the way this is structured.

## Default State

[image]

## Hover State

[image]

```css
.media {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.media__image { display: block; }

.media__body {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3.75em 3em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.media__body:hover { opacity: 1; }

.media__body:after,
.media__body:before {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  bottom: 1em;
  content: '';
  left: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
}

.media__body:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}

.media__body:after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  bottom: 2em;
  top: 2em;
}

.media__body:hover:after,
.media__body:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.media__body h2 { margin-top: 0; }

.media__body p { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
```

```html
<div class="media">
    <img class="media__image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals" alt="" />
    <div class="media__body">
        <h2>Cool Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="/mylink">consectetur adipisicing</a> elit. Nesciunt laboriosam voluptatem necessitatibus cum, tenetur repellat, eaque eos debitis! Quaerat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `CSS3`-only (actually moved into `CSS4` specs) solution would be the `pointer-events` property, e.g.

```
.media__body:hover:after,
.media__body:hover:before {
  ...
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

supported on [all modern browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) but only from `IE11` (on HTML/XML content)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8uz7mx6h/

---

Another solution, supported also on older IE, is to apply `position: relative` with a `z-index` to the paragraph, e.g.

```
.media__body p { 
  margin-bottom: 1.5em; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0nrbjwmg/2/

Comment: Goodness sake, I tried z-index and it didn't work but clearly I had made an error because it does exactly what I expect it to do. Thanks muchly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.media__body p { margin-bottom: 1.5em; 
position: relative;
z-index:999;
```

}

try this !

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly - accepted other answer though as got there first.

Comment: congratz ! thts fine.